# Trophy Troubles

Tags: achievements, psn

I have a question about trophies.
A friend of mine won a trophy while using my PSN account, but if I check my trophy collection (on my console) I don't find it.
I can only view it if I'm comparing my trophies with someone else, and it also appear in the recent obtained trophies.
How can I make it appear also on my collection list?

Can anyone help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: Does the game simply appear in your trophy collection with no trophies, or does it not even appear?

Comment: The game appear displaying 13% complete, but if i compare with other it's at 20% with the new thropies (won by my friend). But if I check my collection is still at 13%

Answer (score 4):

Did you synchronize your account on the PS3 on which the trophy was won? If you got the trophy on his console, but didn't synchronize that console with PSN, then PSN won't know you won that trophy, so your own console won't show the trophies.

Get back to his console, log back onto your account, and synchronize. If you deleted your account on his console before synchronizing your trophies with PSN then any trophies won on his console are lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to sign into PSN and wait for your trophy collection to get synced.

Comment: You don't have to actually wait, you can go over Trophies and push triangle>"Sync with Server"

Comment: I tried but with no result :( Still don't show the trophies gained by my friend.